# Multiple root tags error Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am editing the `setting_main.xml` file of my project in Android Studio, and its giving the below error:

```
Multiple Root Tags
```

**Code Block**:

```
<AbsoluteLayout> 
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioButton ... />
        <RadioButton ... />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView ... />

    <Button ... />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I am not good in android programming but there is something wrong with this code `<AbsoluteLayout     <RadioGroup xmlns ...`  see you didn't closed `<AbsoluteLayout` properly or you unintensionally opened `<RadioGroup xmlns`

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated already. Instead of use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit `setting_main.xml` like this format:

```
<AbsoluteLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup 
         ...>

        <RadioButton
             ...
             />

        <RadioButton
             ... 
             />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        ... />

    <Button
        ... />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `<RadioGroup>` from `<AbsoluteLayout>`. Use this code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
    </RadioGroup>
...
</AbsoluteLayout>
```